# The locus of points forming a right angle, in nonzero curvature

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

Given a line segment $AB$ in the Euclidean plane, the locus of points which form a right angle with $A$ and $B$ is known to be a circle, with $AB$ as a diameter.

[image: The locus of points forming a right angle with AB]

Is this also true for a geodesic segment $AB$ in spherical or hyperbolic space?

In spherical space, let's assume that the distance from $A$ to $B$ is less than $\pi/2$ (but feel free to discuss what happens otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.

When $A$ and $B$ are very close to each other, the solutions approximate a circle, of course (plus its antipodal circle in the case of spherical geometry).

However, as $A$ and $B$ move away from each other, this nice shape cannot be kept, In the spherical case, as the the distance between $A$ and $B$ approaches $\pi/2$, the solution set will approach the *union* of the two great circles centered on $A$ and $B$. This means that for a distance of $\pi/2-\varepsilon$, the solution curve will be sharply curved near the point where those two great circles intersect, and will be almost straight (that is, geodesic) where it passes through $A$ and $B$.

In the hyperbolic case, no matter how far $A$ and $B$ get from each other, no part of the solution can be farther away from the line $AB$ than $\log(1+\sqrt 2)$ which is the height of a 0-0-90 triangle. So the solution curve will be a long and (relatively) skinny oval when $A$ and $B$ are distant from each other.